# Force a line break in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a chat conversation within a div, but very long words fall out. I was advised to use an i-frame, but how? I thought this is for external websites.

[**jsFiddle Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/TWsqQ/2/)

**CSS**

```
.chat{
   width: 230px;
   height: 310px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   background-color: grey;
   border: solid 1px black;
   color: #1855a3;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: @wesley - I deleted the comment after reading the duplicate suggestion. that looks much better

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try to add `word-wrap:break-word;` in your css

Answer (score 3):

Add the CSS rule: `word-break:break-word;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TWsqQ/4/)**

Comment: Same as the suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `word-wrap: break-word;` - works in all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/adamh/TWsqQ/5/

Comment: Same as the suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you're trying to do is prevent horizontal scroll.

You can easily do this with using `overflow-x: hidden;` and `word-wrap: break-word;` so that the long words will breaks into a new line.

**CSS:**

```
.chat{
   width: 230px;
   height: 310px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   background-color: grey;
   border: solid 1px black;
   color: #1855a3;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

See an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/TWsqQ/10/